# AngularJS requests stalling for around 5 minutes

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Having recently made additions to an app (Angular 1.3) that included a Dashboard page (with 5 additional AJAX requests), the AJAX requests now stall for several minutes after visiting each route (state, as it's ui-router).

Looking at the network tab, I can see that there are 5 requests that are pending (stalled), so the 6 request limit is not reached.

Stranger still, this only happens on the remote machine, not on my local server. Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: Is there something in console? This may be caused by violation of the 'Same origin policy'.

Comment: Also, are you able to perform these requests to remote server from command line using `wget` or `curl`?

Comment: @ShimonRachlenko nothing comes up in the console - I'm just trying to perform the request (including to the main website url) via Postman but it's hanging, so I guess this is a server issue.